# GREP to show files WITH text and WITHOUT text

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am trying to search for files with specific text but excluding a certain text and showing only the files.

Here is my code:

```
grep -v "TEXT1" *.* | grep -ils "ABC2"
```

However, it returns:
`(standard input)`

Please suggest. Thanks a lot.

The output should only show the filenames.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. Can you rephrase it? Are you looking for filenames that do not contain `TEXT1`, or files that do not contain `TEXT1` in their content?

Comment: have a look at the following : https://superuser.com/questions/537619/grep-for-term-and-exclude-another-term

Comment: hi , I am looking for file that does not containt TEXT1 and contains ABC2

Comment: thanks.. jcupers, however the grep need to only show the filenames..

Comment: this works :   grep -P '(?=^((?!bar).)*$)foo'   ... output filename:found term.  you can cut it up if needed

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, assuming you want to match these terms anywhere in the file.

```sh
grep -LZ 'TEXT1' *.* | xargs -0 grep -li 'ABC2'
```

- `-L` will match files *not* containing the given search term

  - use `-LiZ` if you want to match `TEXT1` irrespective of case
- The `-Z` option is needed to separate filenames with NUL character and `xargs -0` will then separate out filenames based on NUL character

---

If you want to check these two conditions on same line instead of anywhere in the file:

```sh
grep -lP '^(?!.*TEXT1).*(?i:ABC2)' *.*
```

- `-P` enables PCRE, which I assume you have since `linux` is tagged
- `(?!regexp)` is a negative lookahead construct, so `^(?!.*TEXT1)` will ensure the line doesn't have `TEXT1`
- `(?i:ABC2)` will match `ABC2` case insensitively
- Use `grep -liP '^(?!.*TEXT1).*ABC2'` if you want to match both terms irrespective of case

Comment: Thanks sundeep. Your solution work. Also thanks for the explaination :) Highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
(standard input)
```

This error is due to use of `grep -l` in a pipeline as your second grep command is reading input from stdin not from a file and `-l` option is printing `(standard input)` instead of the filename.

You can use this alternate solution in a single `awk` command:

```sh
awk '/ABC2/ && !/TEXT1/ {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice code sir, could you please do let me know why we need `*.*` here? Can't be just `*` used here? Will be grateful if you could explain this one, thank you.

Comment: I used `*.*` because OP also had it, assuming filenames have extensions with `.` in filenames

Comment: oh ok, in case of `*` files with `.` will not be picked up? Sorry haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Files with `.` will also be picked up with just `*` but it will also pickup directories whereas `*.*` is more restrictive to match filenames with extensions only.